# Simple probability with dice

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose you roll a 6-sided dice 6 times.

a. What is the probability that all of the rolls show either 1, 2, or 3?

- Would the answer be $(1/2)^6$?

b. What is the probability that all of the rolls show the same value?

- $(1/6)^6$?

c. What is the probability that all of the rolls show unique values (none of them match)?

- I have no idea how to do this. Would this progress like this? 1/6!

d. What is the probability that the first two rolls match, the second two rolls match
(and are different from the previous ones) and that the last two rolls match (and
are different from any of the previous ones)?

- I have no idea how to do this

Comment: First is correct. Second is not, should be $(1/6)^5$. Third is $6!/6^6$. For the last, there are (6)(5)(4)$  favourables.

Comment: For part b) I believe you should multiply by $6$ since there are $6$ ways it could happen.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following way for solving this kind of problems:

- For all questions, the total number of combinations is $6^6$
- A) The number of combinations is $3^6$, hence the probability is $\frac{3^6}{6^6}$
- B) The number of combinations is $6$, hence the probability is $\frac{6}{6^6}$
- C) The number of combinations is $6!$, hence the probability is $\frac{6!}{6^6}$
- D) The number of combinations is $\binom63\cdot3!$, hence the probability is $\frac{\binom63\cdot3!}{6^6}$